# Should I structure my CV in sections for relevant experience to PhD and day job work if the two are unrelated?

Tags: phd, cv

I am applying for my PhD currently [in Music]. Part of the application concerns sending a CV. When I applied for my master's I just sent them my normal work CV [which had nothing to do with music] and that seemed to do the job to get the application through.

However, I have done many music-related things over the years [A&R, promotion, journalism etc] and have constructed a CV around these for my new application as 'relevant experience' to the PhD. Should I include another section for my day job[s] as well [which have nothing to do with music] or should I just keep to relevant to the academic application?

Answer (score 1):

I've been applying for PhDs in a completely different field, but was advised to leave employment history out of the CV unless they're relevant to the PhD.

Comment: Thanks, Katy. I was thinking this too. I mean, I've done my fair share of paid painting and decorating over the years but won't be including that...